# Retrofit 2 sequential Requests using asynchronous network calls with retry

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android, okhttp

I am trying to send a network request to an api using retrofit, and when I get back response, use part of that response in another call, i used call, and rxjava as suggested, but i always have the second request executed before the first one

```
public interface ChannelRequest {

    @POST("authenticate_with_options")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<Channel> getAuthenticationChannel(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params);


    @POST("check")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<Channel> getAuthenticationStatus(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params);
}
```

ss

```
        Observable<Channel> call2 = mAPI.gettheChannel().getAuthenticationStatus(Constants.HTTP.PARAMSAUTH);
        Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).retry(3);
        Subscription subscription2 = call2
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // optional if you do not wish to override the default behavior
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Channel>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                            HttpException response = (HttpException) e;
                            int code = response.code();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Channel channel) {

                        Log.d("AuthStatus", "onResponse: " + Channel.getChannel());

                    }
                });
```

I am not sure if i have to use RxJava anymore, what would be the best practice to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't look like your issue (as there is only one call to your api in your example)

Nevertheless, you can look at the operator `flatMap` to call another observable, with the result of a previous call.

```
 mAPI.gettheChannel().getAuthenticationStatus(Constants.HTTP.PARAMSAUTH)
                     // use the result from a previous call to perform another one
                     .flatMap(result -> mApi.gettheChannel().getAuthentificationChannel(result))
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // optional if you do not wish to override the default behavior
                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                     .subscribe();
```

Comment: I did this the below, would it work ?      
             
`.flatMap(new Func1<AccepttoChannel, Observable<AccepttoChannel>>() {

                    @Override
                    public Observable<AccepttoChannel> call(AccepttoChannel accepttoChannel) {
                        //String token = ... // TODO extract token.
                        Constants.HTTP.PARAMSAUTH.put("channel",accepttoChannel.getChannel());
                        return mAPI.getAccepttoChannel().getAuthenticationChannel(Constants.HTTP.PARAMSAUTH);
                    }
                })`